# Laravel Get newly inserted id from a relationship on save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a morphMany relationship for comments that are related to a question Model I would like to know how you get the newly inserted id when saving a new comment Model.

```
    public function postComment() {

    if(Request::ajax() && Auth::check()) {
        //Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));

        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $comment->body = Helper::strip_tags(Input::get('body'));
        $question_id = Input::get('question_id');
        $question = Question::find($question_id);

        // here in the if statement how do I get the newly created id of a comment
        if($question->comments()->save($comment)) {         

            return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'body' => Input::get('body'), 
                'userlink' => HTML::linkRoute('profile', Auth::user()->username, array('id' => Auth::user()->id)), 'date' => date("F j, Y, g:i a") ));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'body' => Input::get('body')));
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The saved comment record will be returned on save:

```
$comment = $question->comments()->save($comment);

if($comment) {
    // Comment was saved

    $comment->id;
} else {
    // Comment was not saved
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it gives me undefined when I put it in my Response::json

Comment: I just tested this now and works as expected. Do you have a primary key on your comments model? You can also try `$comment->getKey()` to retrieve the models primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can reference it just by doing `$comment->id`. Have you already tried this?

Comment: Show me some example code how it should look. I tried it and I get undefined when I put it in my ajax response Response::json(array('id' => $comment->id));

Comment: @KDM I would try `dd($comment->id)`. If it returns a number and not null, then the problem lies elsewhere. Let me know what happens so I can continue to try and help

Answer (score 1):

Normally `$comment->id` should work, but you can try getting the inserted id instead which should be the comment's after `save`:

```
DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```